# Sum of specific property in Json using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, sum

I am using Asp.net MVC , and from my ActionResult I am returning data using TempData. Like this

```
 TempData["chartmodel"] = new
        {
            Labels = res.Select(x => x.ServiceName).ToList(),                                  //changes hotel name to service
            BadData = res.Select(x => x.Development).ToList(),
            ExcellentData = res.Select(x => x.Excellent).ToList(),
            GoodData = res.Select(x => x.Average).ToList(),
            VeryGoodData = res.Select(x => x.Good).ToList(),
            PoorData = res.Select(x => x.unsatisfactory).ToList(),
        };
        return View(res);
```

In My View i am encoding it in json like

```
 var chartModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(TempData["chartmodel"]));
```

Now I just want to Sum only Excellent Property. Let say I have data in

chartModel.ExcellentData = `2,3,5`

I want to sum it in a variable as `10`

Comment: Use LINQ: `SumOfExcellentData = res.Select(x => x.Excellent).Sum()` and then retrieve that inside `chartModel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `reduce`:

```
var sumVariable = chartModel.ExcellentData.reduce(function(e, a) { return e + a; }, 0)
```